# How to destroy the current user session from rails through graphql mutation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, session-cookies, logout

I am trying to clear user sessions through a graphql mutation which takes user_id as an argument and destroys the user session and sends a message, which will further be used by frontend to sign out.

```
  argument :user_id, ID, required: true
  field :message, String, null: true

  def resolve(user_id:)
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, 'User not found.' unless user.present?
    destroy_user_session(user_id)
    user.save!
    { message: 'User session cleared'}
  end
  
  private

  def destroy_user_session(user_id)
    binding.pry
    session = context[:session]
    session.clear
    raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, 'Failed to clear session.' unless session.empty?
  end
end
```

But the problem is, the user session is not getting destroyed properly here. I am testing it using `localhost:3000/api/graphql` where I call the mutation first and then calls some other query that are accessible once the user is logged in and unfortunately both are being called instead of throwing error like `authorization is requried`. I tried several steps from different sites but still got stuck here.

Comment: please share what you have on your context object

Comment: This mutation is using graphql_controller to handle the user request, my code base has following object as context
 def context
    {
      session: session,
      current_user: @current_user,
     controller: self
    }
  end

Comment: which controller is your graphql_controller inheriting from? is it application controller ?

Comment: Yes, it is being inherited from application controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your graphql_controller is inheriting from application_controller you should have access to `sign_out` method if you are using `devise` so if you try calling `context[:controller].sign_out` it should work

```
  def destroy_user_session(user_id)
    context[:controller].sign_out
    session = context[:session]
    session.clear
    raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, 'Failed to clear session.' unless session.empty?
  end
```

Comment: Also, you need not write session.clear because the session has already been logged out.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach and it worked and now I am able to logout.. Thanks @Nirajan Pokharel for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
def destroy_user_session
  context[:controller].sign_out
end
```

Above code would suffice. You need not to write any further. (Follow up answer for Nirajan's answer)